# Scatterplot between independent and dependent variable has two patterns

Tags: regression, logistic

My scatterplot between the explanatory and response variable is as follows,

[image]

It shows two patterns here. I want to fit a regression model for this. I am not able to understand what does these two patterns denote. Can anybody help me in understanding this?

Comment: Do you know why you have two patterns? Do you have more variables? For example, is there a binary variable that separates the data into the two trends?

Comment: @ Nirvan Sengupta I have only two variables. I am not sure why there are two patterns. That is why I thought I can ask for an opinion. What does two patterns mean here.

Comment: It looks like your population has a heterogeneous response to the explanatory variable.  You might want to try to test for heterogeneity of treatment effect -- for [example](http://www.nber.org/papers/t0324.pdf).  Depending on the context, this outcome might also be consistent with an intent-to-treat effect when failure to treat is high.  Also, your response is clearly not binary so I don't see why you have the logistic tag.

Comment: There are a variety of possible explanations for such a pattern. e.g. (i) maybe there's a missing explanatory variable (in the simplest case, a binary one that interacts with $x$); or (ii) maybe the response just has a naturally bimodal conditional distribution, where one of the modes is strongly related to $x$ and one is not. There are other possibilities (e.g. maybe there's some latent effect that's suppressing "middling" values of $y$.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying statistical model you're interested in is a "[mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)," so called because two distributions are mixed together.

In order to fit a regression mixture model, you need to fit both the (latent) class label and the slopes of the two classes. Typically this is done by alternating between fitting class labels and fitting slopes until it converges. See [this implementation and explanation](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/10/19/em-and-regression-mixture-modeling/) by John Myles White for more detail.

Comment: I agree in suspecting something similar. However, OP has explicitly stated that there are no other variables, so this remains an ideal counsel.

Comment: @NickCox, I think he means imputing a latent class label via Gaussian finite mixture modeling, & fitting the slopes via OLS, all via the EM algorithm.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. I've edited (latent) into the answer to hopefully make it clearer.